# Comparing datetime field in python, not just date or time , Type Error :Can't compare unicode to date.datetime field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Have created a Django datetime field 'time' and want to have some comparisions based on that. But it gives the error that Can't compare unicode to date.datetime field

here's what I am doing

```
if form.is_valid():
   if formdata['time']==datetime.datetime.min:
       formdata['time'] = datetime.date.now
   if formadata['time'] < last_entry_time:
       error_message
```

What I could figure out was, that the first condition returns a false even if they are equal ( by default set to min.) and in the second if condition it gives the error..

Wen through the python documentation for datetime field and its mentioned that it doesn't raise a type error for '==' and '!=' comparison. So basically there is type mismatch in both the conditional statements

Comment: what do you think `datetime.datetime.min` is?

Comment: should be a datetime object

Comment: Ok. And maybe `formdata['time']` or `formdata.cleaned_data['time']` is not a datetime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attributes in `form.cleaned_data` to compare. Attributes in `cleaned_data` will be of appropriate data type.

e.g.

```
if form.is_valid():
   if form.cleaned_data['time']==datetime.datetime.min:
   ....
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Is there any other method which works other than this?

I want to do this

    if form.is_valid():
       if formdata.cleaned_data['time']==datetime.datetime.min:
           formdata['time'] = datetime.date.now()
       if formadata.cleaned_data['time'] < last_entry_time:
           error_message
    elif( formdata.cleaned_data['request-id'] == somthing)

In the elif part, I get the error attribute Error, no cleand_data for 'form'

Comment: @Himanshu, Actually, I didn't get completely the problem you mentioned. However, `form.cleaned_data` will be there if form is valid. It seems you are validating time, which you should do in clean method of field (`clean_time()`).